# How to send and receive data sparingly client

Tags: php, http, connection, client

User A connects to example.php

I know that when the client connects to example.php it tries to receive all the available content on the page...

Im also aware that if a page contains php lets say that contains a sleep(10) that the page will wait for the php to finish...

So my question how long with the client wait to get a response. Putting the users browser out of the question how long is the connection valid and open waiting for a response.

The why(not really stack overflow content beyond here)...if your so inclined
...I have a client device(not a browser) this device makes a http request to example.php...

I want the device to stay connected to my server for as long as possible...as well as maybe my server sends some data occasionally

Comment: the connection will stay open as long as you keep sending it data in a timely manner (most browsers time out after 5 minutes of no data being received) or until the user closes the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is [long-polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling).  If your non-browser HTTP client supports it, you may also want to look at [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), which allows you to establish a connection via JavaScript from the client to the server and maintain an open connection where either the client or the server can initiate sending data back and forth over that established connection.

Comment: Ahh someone with a little info on where im trying to get! just getting to the info im looking for is whats giving me such a hard time... Ok thanks for your answer....Feel free to elaborate more if you want...Im truly in the how the hell am i going to do this stage but im staying creative and open minded...Id love to hear more if you would be willing to share.

Comment: I really want to achieve this with if you will as little as abstraction as possible. I was thinking of having the device request a page where i have javascript constantly outputting data to keep the connection alive and when there is actually data to transfer this would of course occur. Is this considered PUSH and maybe more descriptive Pushlet from the links you provided? If you have more to elaborate i would be happy to sweeten the deal for an answer

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what your client device is (you said it wasn't a browser), because I don't know what it's capable of.  WebSockets is your best bet if you can do that, because it will handle more a PUSH like you're looking for.  This library is a PHP WebSockets server: http://socketo.me.  You use JavaScript to establish the connection from the browser.  From there, you can send data back and forth, and each time data is sent from one side to the other, and event is triggered on the receiving side so you can respond to the incoming data.

Comment: My client is a micro controller :) so hopefully that highlights the issue a little better...Ill have to look into sockets as its not too easy to implement things on the client side

Comment: Which is unfortunate being that the controller is not a browser ....and the one of the first line on that web page that u suggested says,"persistent connection from a web browser to a server. " :(

Comment: Using WebSockets would require at least JavaScript support on the client side.

Comment: What about just Sockets?

Comment: You could use regular IP Sockets, but then you're building that yourself from scratch, so your micro controller would have to allow you to do that.  You'd also have to built the IP Socket server.

Comment: Im already using sockets on my micro controller to connect to the web...I just dont know how to handle this on the web side...I cant just initiate a connection to the client due to it being on a internal network and port forwarding is not an option...Im left to determine a method for which the client establishes a connection and then my web side replies

Comment: You would have to build a socket process that runs on the server that accepts the socket connection from the client and holds it open. If you want to maintain a persistent reliable connection, you'd have to use something other than HTTP that you built yourself.